# Change xdrp resolution

Tags: kde-plasma, xrdp

I currently use Windows RDP to remote into my Ubuntu desktop running KDE and xrdp. When I do this from my desktop the resolution is fine. When I remote from my laptop the resolution is too small. Is there a simple way to change the screen resolution when I remote in from my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows RDP, look for the 'Options' button on the lower left side of the connection window. Then switch tabs to 'Display'. Then adjust the slider and try connecting after making the change.

Answer (score -1):

**In "Remote Desktop" on Windows.** Choose the remote PC that want to set the resolution...

[**Step 1: >> "···" >> "Edit"**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS9Bs.png)

[**Step 2: >> "Show more"**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PZBK.png)

[**Step 3: In "Display settings" >> "Set my remote session resolution to:"**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diwLT.png)

[**Step 4: Select the resolution you want** (e.g. 1920x1080)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83oD4.png)

[**Step 5: Back to connect the remote PC**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRBCW.png)

[ All Done! ]